Missing objects in the collections
I'm having a problem with objects showing up in the collections I can add a new object just fine and it shows up. I've added a cube however it isn't showing up here.

Not sure what I've done so I don't Know how to fix it and I can't find a solution online. Can anyone help with this please.

Hello could you please share your file?
